# how to import data into 1 table, related data into another table with id from 1st?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

This may seem like a noob question, but I'm trying to write a CSV importer for Wordpress, and struggling with the problem of related data that has to tie in using 2 tables.

The CSV will NOT have unique ids. The resulting data MUST have unique key ids in 1 table, and that unique id must the populate another table in many rows with other info.

I'm simply trying to import posts into wp_posts, then have other information in my csv end up in the wp_postmeta with the properly-associated post_id from wp_posts.id ... which is an auto-increment number.

I know this is probably 1st-year stuff for many of you, but I'm tired and at my whit's end. 
Am I incorrect in thinking I can write a SQL query to do this without complex php surrounding the iteration? Or am I just code-drunk from working on the larger project for 4 days wihtout sleep?

Thanks.

Comment: You are much better off handling the parsing and inserts with php.  I'd suggest however, to import your CSV into a staging table and do all your data manipulations (like creating id's and populating them over to other tables) in SQL after the file has been imported.

Comment: it's a good thing the csv doesn't have unique ids of its own - there's no guarantee those ids wouldn't conflict with something already in your db.